# Traversing every cell possible in 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am not sure what to call this problem, but I'm sure it has a name. Otherwise finding an answer would be simpler.

Given a "map" of cells such as:

```
O - - -
- X - -
- X X -
- - - -
```

where O = starting position, X = obstacle and - = unvisited. I want to traverse this map (which I've stored as a 2D array) and visit as many cells as possible without touching a visited cell.

My algorithm is as follows:

1. If I can go right, go right.
2. Else if I can go down, go down.
3. Else if I can go left, go left.
4. Else if I can go up, go up.
5. If I'm stuck, backtrack and mark that cell "unvisitable", and go back to 1.

So two problems:

- For bigger maps, the number of obstacles and where they are placed often causes my algorithm to not reach a lot of cells. I've tried different orders of steps 1-4 (i.e. always going up if I can etc.) but it obviously depends on the given map.
- I don't know when to stop. If my algorithm reaches the "end", i.e. I have actually visited every possible cell, it doesn't stop and just backtracks all the way back to the start.

So my question I guess is: is there a better way to implement this, or how do I tweak my current algorithm to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a name: the longest path problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

In graph form, make the edges from a free cell to a blocked cell have infinite weight and all of the others have a weight of 1 (or some other constant). There is no "efficient" (in algorithmic complexity terms) solution to this problem (if you find one you'll be famous!)

To address your two problems:

1. You are right that, depending on the obstacles, you will not be able to visit certain squares but it also depends on the starting point. It is entirely possible that many squares will be unreachable; for example, there might be obstacles completely surrounding the start point and then all are unreachable.
2. For your current algorithm, you can stop when you've backtracked to the start square and then have no more moves. Otherwise your algorithm looks correct. The order of steps 1-4 will not make any difference in the end. In order to know which path is the longest you'll still have to try them all (with this approach).

Edit: I am not sure I understood step 5 when I read it earlier; the current square should NOT be marked unreachable even if you are stuck (if you are on that square then you visited it) but the surrounding squares are (except the one you came from). As long as you don't mark the current square unvisitable the backtracking algorithm should find the longest path correctly.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I will have to check this out. As I said in the other reply in here, I've changed my algorithm a bit. So basically what I do now is make one traversal to eventually visit every cell in order to find the longest move stack. Once we visited every cell, I just loop through the move stack and move according to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm doesn't work because of cases like this:

```
O - - -
X - - X
```

because your algorithm will first go all the way right

```
O 1 2 3
X - - X
```

and mark the rightmost cell blocked when backtracking, so it will never find the optimal

```
O 1 4 5
X 2 3 X
```

---

You could solve this problem in a generic way by treating this as a graph problem and simple applying any longest-path algorithm (which is NP-hard in general) but I'm not sure if you're familiar with that approach.

A probably simpler way to look at it is this:

- Keep track of the current position and all the steps you've taken to get there.
- For every position, you will eventually try stepping in every direction in the order right (R), down (D), left (L), up (U).
- When you tried all directions for a certain position (i.e., you tried U), take a step back by doing the inverse of the last step you did.

---

An example probably helps. Let's consider the same example again. I use C for the current position and # for a visited cell. We keep track of the stack of moves and of the last step in case of backtracking.

```
C - - -  Stack: []
X - - X  Backtracked move: -
```

Step right

```
# C - -  Stack: [R]
X - - X  Backtracked move: -
```

Step right

```
# # C -  Stack: [R, R]
X - - X  Backtracked move: -
```

Step right

```
# # # C  Stack: [R, R, R]
X - - X  Backtracked move: -
```

Try right, down, left, and up, notice you're stuck and backtrack, i.e. take the reverse of right (left)

```
# # C -  Stack: [R, R]
X - - X  Backtracked move: R
```

The last backtracked move was right, so now try the next move, i.e., step down

```
# # # -  Stack: [R, R, D]
X - C X  Backtracked move: -
```

Try right, try down, step left

```
# # # -  Stack: [R, R, D, L]
X C # X  Backtracked move: -
```

Stuck again, so backtrack

```
# # # -  Stack: [R, R, D]
X - C X  Backtracked move: L
```

The last backtracked move was left, so now try the next move, i.e., try up. Notice we're stuck and backtrack further.

Fast forwarding to the first interesting next step:

```
# C - -  Stack: [R]
X - - X  Backtracked move: R
```

Last one was right, so continue with down.

```
# # - -  Stack: [R, D]
X C - X  Backtracked move: -
```

You probably get the point by now, so I'm just fast-forwarding all the way:

```
# # # C  Stack: [R, D, R, U, R]
X # # X  Backtracked move: -
```

And backtracking all the way:

```
C - - -  Stack: []
X - - X  Backtracked move: R
```

Last move was right, so try down, left, and up. And you're done.

Along the way you keep track of the longest path you've seen and that's your answer.

Comment: I somewhat improved on my algorithm since i first asked this question. Sorry for not checking my inbox sooner, I completely forgot about it. What I changed now is that whenever I reach the code block for backtracking, I make a snapshot of all the move stack as it is at that point. I then compare the snapshot with the last snapshot (if there is one). I then replace the old one with the new one if it's bigger, i.e. has more moves. Repeat until we've visited all visitable cells, and we should have our best path. It's only about 80% efficient though.

Comment: Hmm. I get the feeling this algorithm is very time consuming if for every obstacle we have to traverse it with multiple tries. If I understand you correctly we have to check for different move patterns at every obstacle?

Comment: @cloudbells, this algorithm never does double work. The problem is known to be NP hard so you should expect it to take exponential time. This algorithm finds every possible path from start to finish and nothing more. It's asymptotically optimal.